# java binary to decimal converter

Tags: java, binary, conditional-statements, decimal, converters

This is one of my first Java programs and I am very confused why it doesn't work. Help?

In addition, the else statement prints despite 'input' being given a correct value. Is there a structure for conditional statements that I'm missing?

```
package beginning;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

// VERY BROKEN

public class BinaryDecimalConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Number Base To Convert: 1) Binary 2) Decimal ::");
        String binOrDec = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Number ::");
        long number = sc.nextInt();
        double result = 0;

        if ((binOrDec.equals("1")) || (binOrDec.equals("Binary"))) {
            char[] bin = ("" + number).toCharArray(); // conversion must be String >> char[]
            int index = bin.length - 1;
            double aggregate = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bin.length; i++) {
                aggregate = ((Math.pow(2, i)) * (bin[index])); // when using Math.pow(a, b) - a must be 'double' data type
                index = index - 1;
                result = result + aggregate;
            }   
        }
        if (binOrDec.equals("2") || binOrDec.equals("Decimal")) {
            // decimal-binary converter, unfinished.
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }

        System.out.println("" + number + " >> " + result);
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code says: if `binOrDec` is `2` or `Decimal`, do nothing, else, print `invalid input`. Computers do what you tell em to. I think you probably want an `else` in front of that line to checks for 2/Decimal.

'doesn't work' is not a great start. Help us help you:

- If it does not compile, tell us the error the compiler gives you and make sure the line numbers match up or you otherwise make it possible for us to know where to look.
- If it does compile, but you get an error when you run it, supply the error, as well as any input you provided that resulted in the error.
- If it does compile, and run, and you get output, but it is not the output you expected, explain what you typed in to get it, what you did expect, and why.

Your `bin` array is of type `char[]`. If I supply the binary number `1010` for example, it contains 4 characters: 1, 0, 1, and 0. That's *characters*. ascii characters. The ascii character `1` has a large numeric value (not `1`):

```java
char c = '1';
System.out.println(1 * c);
```

The above prints.... `49`.

So: `aggregate = ((Math.pow(2, i)) * (bin[index]));` is multiplying by `48` or `49` depending on whether that character is a 1 or a 0. I think you may be looking for `if (bin[index] == '1') aggregate = Math.pow(2, i);`.

Comment: I didn't realise numbers had a ascii character equivalent and that aren't treated as numbers, my program is working now - thanks!